# creating a key value pairs from extracted values in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, hash

i have a string i trying to match a text and it works as i expected

```
import re
s = "This week end is very good"
v = re.findall(r'(This)',s)
print v
```

output:

```
['This']
```

But when i try to do a multiple matches it is not working

```
import re
s = "This week end is very good"
v = re.findall(r'(This)(week)',s)
print v
```

output:

```
[]
```

How to make a multiple matches and i want output like key value pairs

example output:

```
"This" : "week"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must match the space character. Try this:

```
v = re.findall(r'(This) (week)',s)
```

Result:

```
v = re.findall(r'(This) (week)',s)
print v
[('This', 'week')]
```

To turn that into a key-value pair, simply call the `dict` constructor:

```
d = dict(v)
print d
{'This': 'week'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alternation operator `|` if you want to  use multiple search patterns.

```
>>> s = "This week end is very good"
>>> v = re.findall(r'This|week',s)
>>> ' : '.join(v)
'This : week'
```

Comment: Your regex knowledge never fails to impress. +1 :)